# Move element in a button tag

Tags: html, css, button, web

I have this piece of code:

```
<div style="float: right">       
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link colorGrey " ng-click="ViewFactory.ShowView('WelcomepageModule')" ng-show="({IsActive: true, IsVisible: true, IsMandatory: true}).IsVisible" ng-disabled="!({IsActive: true, IsVisible: true, IsMandatory: true}).IsActive" ng-required="({IsActive: true, IsVisible: true, IsMandatory: true}).IsMandatory" required="required" style="font-size: 1.5em;">     
        <span class="fa fa-times" style="margin-right: 2px"></span> Close                                 
</button>
</div>
```

I want to align the font awesome image with the center of the word "Close".
How can I do it ?

Comment: `align` to? `right` or `left`? both `center` ?!

Comment: I want to move the image to the top with respect to the word "close"

Comment: Now they are aligned to the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple version of your code. Please try with the concept of the following syntax.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link colorGrey ne-cls">
<span class="fa fa-times icn-cls" style="margin-right: 2px; "></span> <span class="txt">Close</span> 
 </button>
```

**CSS**

```
.ne-cls {diplay:inline-block;}
.icn-cls{vertical-align:middle;}
.txt {vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want the icon to align to the top or you want the icon on top. So, here's both.

You can make the contents of the button as block and use the below css.

```
<div style="float: right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link colorGrey" style="font-size: 1.5em;">
    <span class="fa fa-times" style="margin-right: 2px"></span>
    <span>Close</span>
  </button>
</div>

button > * {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/odspgxak/)

or

```
button > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/odspgxak/1/)